# DeepLearning4j examples maven project unable to be processed by Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, deeplearning4j

As shown in the screenshot there is a dependency of the dl4j-0.4-examples project that is unable to be loaded by intellij.

> Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file
>   for artifact 'com.github.jai-imageio-core.jar': Invalid JDK version in
>   profile "java8-and-higher': Unbounded range [1.8

[image]

A similar problem resolved in this question

https://github.com/google/gson/issues/596

> as quick fix open the pom file at your local repository and add ')'
>   and should  looks like
>
> 91         [1.8,)
>
> save and execute again

But in *this* case  there is no `jdk` tag: so that approach can not be used.

Has anyone found a workaround to load this project into intellij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owners of the project have recognized this as an issue. If you would like to follow along here is the bug tracker:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-0.4-examples/issues/76

**Update** 2/28/16: The resolution:  I needed to do

```
 brew switch maven 3.3.9
```

There were multiple versions of maven installed on my machine but I did not know about `brew switch`.  So some ways maven was working without doing the `switch` - but for *this* project a completely *clean* maven installation was required.

Comment: Please join the community on Gitter if you can: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j